# How to Use Custom Local Fonts with Chakra UI and Next.js

Tags: next.js, chakra-ui

I've downloaded 5 different weights of a particular font and they are in a folder in my NextJS v14 app. I want to be able to apply these fonts/font weights to any Chakra UI component as I wish something like:
`<Text fontFamily="my-font-500">Hello</Text>`
I have come across documentation [in the chakra docs](https://chakra-ui.com/community/recipes/using-fonts) but it isn't working as expected. Has anyone done this before or have an idea how to go about it?

From the Chakra docs the process is

Fonts.tsx

```
import { Global } from '@emotion/react'

const Fonts = () => (
  <Global
    styles={`
      /* latin */
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Heading Font Name';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-display: swap;
        src: url('./fonts/headingfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('./fonts/headingfont.woff') format('woff');
        unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
      }
      /* latin */
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Body Font Name';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-display: swap;
        src: url('./fonts/bodyfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('./fonts/bodyfont.woff') format('woff');
        unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
      }
      `}
  />
)

export default Fonts
```

theme.ts

```
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react'

const theme = extendTheme({
  fonts: {
    heading: `'Heading Font Name', sans-serif`,
    body: `'Body Font Name', sans-serif`,
  },
})

export default theme
```

```
import {
  ChakraProvider,
  Container,
  Stack,
  Heading,
  Text,
} from '@chakra-ui/react'
import Fonts from './fonts'
import theme from './theme'

const App = () => (
  <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
    <Fonts />
    <Container>
      <Stack>
        <Heading>The spectacle before us was indeed sublime.</Heading>
        <Text>
          Apparently we had reached a great height in the atmosphere, for the
          sky was a dead black, and the stars had ceased to twinkle. By the same
          illusion which lifts the horizon of the sea to the level of the
          spectator on a hillside, the sable cloud beneath was dished out, and
          the car seemed to float in the middle of an immense dark sphere, whose
          upper half was strewn with silver. Looking down into the dark gulf
          below, I could see a ruddy light streaming through a rift in the
          clouds.
        </Text>
      </Stack>
    </Container>
  </ChakraProvider>
)
```

This sets all headings to use 'Heading Font Name' font/font weight. What if I have the font files for 'Heading Font Name Bold' and 'Heading Font Name SemiBold' and I have headings on my page whose fonts weight vary between bold and semibold, how do I go about it?